# How to relate a product dimension with a sales fact

Tags: data-modeling, data-warehouse, business-intelligence

I have been studying datawarehouse in the last couple days, particularly, i have been reading *The Data Wharehouse Toolkit - The Definitive Guide to Dimensional Modeling* by Kimball and Ross.

Uppon that reading, i came to the 1st exapmle where there is a sales fact and it related to a product dimension, as you can see in the bellow image:

[image]

I think i can grasp the gist of how this relationship allows us to rotate the "cube" slicing and dicing data, however this is where i get lost:

In this example and many others on the web product is a one-to-one relationship with sales, which is fine i guess for most cases. But this generates a sales registtry for at least each kind of product that was in one sale.

So supposing i bought 1 banana, 2 apples and 1 orange, this would yield at least 3 sales registry. Again, which is fine i guess as it is storing the sale's ticket ID in the sales fact, we still can relate all itens in a given sale.

However if this was an use case: relate products on sales say i want to get every sale that had a banana and get stuff like: how many items each of these sales had, their price cost, their profit, stuff like that...
Wouldn't be better if the fact-product relation were Fact-one_to_many-Product relationship? Where fact would hold the sale's ticket ID and products would have its foreign key referencing where they are from or something?

I reckon these metrics should be in the fact table, and not in the product table as i think i would want. So, is this me not fighting my urge to normalize it or does it make sense in the way i would want to do that kind of filtering -> [given all sales with X product, get data from other products in the same sale].

If i were to follow the guidelines, product dimension would have one registry for every exclusive kind of product the store would have correct? And all the measurements i want i would store it on the fact itself, like price cost, sales price, profit, etc...

On the other hand, if i were to one-to-many product dimension would have many copies of each product. Which is bad, i think. However, i think it would give me better queries in that regard.

As you can see, i'm a beginer and really in the early stages of this path, so if you would endulge me in a Explain Like I'm Five kind of answer I would appreciate.

**EDITED:**

Sorry @Nick.McDermaid, you are right. I meant from the perspective of the sales fact where for every sale fact i will have only one product, but are correct that for one product it can have N sales related. And so, we have one record of product in the database for every different product on our store. This is the right way to do it, how to rightfully model it. Also, the many indicator is the "sales quantity" i'm guessing.

Anyhow, while this allows for slicing and dicing when/if we have sales as the point of view, but what if i want to for example:
Get all sales that had a banana in it, with all the other items in those sales. We can still do it with this structure but its harder than if the products were repeated  and we had the sale id as a foreign key in the product table.
Cuz ultimetly i want to get all the sales(and products within that sale) that had a banana. And then take metrics out of them.

Comment: "product is a one-to-one relationship with sales". It's not. It's a one to many. The diagram is missing the many indicator on the sales side. Does this answer all of your questions (you have a lot of questions - difficult to answer!)

Comment: Agreed, products are the different products that can be sold, and sales are the actual sales of the products, hence one product can be in many sales records, and one sales record relates to just one product.

Comment: In response to your edit: the product should have nothing to do with the sale. They are representing the actual products. The fact.sale could have the sale id in the record which would allow you to a) identify all the sales ids that have bananas in them and then b) show you all the other items for sales matching that sales id.

Answer (score 0):

What you are somewhat hinting at would be a degenerate dimension, consisting of the sales id/invoice #/purchase order # of the transaction that took place.  The whole purpose of a degenerate dimension is to group items that are related by a meaningless piece of data.  For example, a PO # of A1234 is meaningless on its own, it doesn't tell you anything about the purchase. However, it can be used to identify other meaningful data, such as the date of purchase of the products for the customer.  In that context, the PO # is defined by the collection of the entities it brings together to describe an event.

Another critical concept in data-warehousing is the abstraction of the schema in the database from the model in the cube.  You don't join and group data in a cube model.  You slice and filter.  There are no foreign keys in a cube model.  Those are used in the underlying data schema, but all of that work is handled behind the scenes of the cube model.